# Formatting a date to the senders local time

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am having a hard time taking a UTC Date string with an offset and adjusting the time to the users local time exactly. I receive a date on our server say: `2017-06-21T20:26:28.744Z` and I need to turn it into a timestamp of the senders local time. For the sake of this example lets say the offset is 6 hours.

**I know that this is probably wrong and that the z portion explains what the offset really is**.

I need to turn `2017-06-21T20:26:28.744Z` into `2017-06-21T14:26:28` using moment.

Doing this seems to give me the UTC portion of the string and chops off the offset. I need to use the offset to adjust the hours/ minutes back

```
moment
  .utc('2017-06-21T20:26:28.744Z')
  .local()
  .format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss')
  // 2017-06-21T20:26:28" 
  // I need 2017-06-21T14:26:28
```

Comment: `moment.utc('2017-06-21T20:26:28.744Z').local().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss')`?

Comment: Tried that to. I am actually going to update to show it that way in the example

Comment: Your code seems fine, it prints `2017-06-21T22:26:28` in my environment (`Europe/Rome` timezone `UTC+2`) that is the right output.

Comment: I don't want it in the environment running the date. If the offset is 6 hours and they send the hour as the 20th hour I need to save it as 14

Comment: If the offset is 6 hours then 2017-06-21T20:26:28.744Z  should be 2017-06-22T02:26:28.744+0600.

Comment: Sorry for confusion I was meaning a -6 offset. Either way with the method above if I go into my computer and mess with time settings then every call changes depending on the time on my computer. I never want it to be relative to the machine receiving the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`utcOffset`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/)

> Setting the UTC offset by supplying minutes. Note that once you set an offset, it's fixed and won't change on its own (i.e there are no DST rules). If you want an actual time zone -- time in a particular location, like `America/Los_Angeles`, consider [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/).
>
> If the input is less than `16` and greater than `-16`, it will interpret your input as hours instead.

Here a working sample:

```js
console.log( moment
  .utc('2017-06-21T20:26:28.744Z')
  .utcOffset(-6)
  .format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss') );
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to use moment-timezone, you can use [`tz()`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/) method:

```js
console.log( moment
  .utc('2017-06-21T20:26:28.744Z')
  .tz('America/Chicago')
  .format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss') );
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.13/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this is closer to what I want but I don't want to hardcode the offset or timezone. Server is running in AWS and could be anywhere. Also as far as I know the end of a time stamp is the offset. I just need to learn how to extract that data and then I could use that to move the time backward/forward

Comment: The offset is usually a value that tells the difference with UTC (e.g. `+02:00`, `-06:00`, ...). Your input ends with `Z` that means that your value is UTC (`+00:00` offset). It's not clear to me which criteria you want to use _"to move the time backward/forward"_.

Comment: I had a horrible understanding of dates when I was doing this. I didn't realize that the number before the z was milliseconds. Duh I know, I thought it was some calculation of my offset from utc. I was able to get this done. Thanks for the time guys! For the record your answer is not wrong and I would upvote it but I don't want to make it seem like my understanding was correct at all

Comment: @StephenBolton I'm glad you now understand dates better and you solved your problem. You are free to upvote or not this answer, I tried to give to most relevant solution to your original question, basically the code in the question was fine and you simply need to better understand how dates are represented. My answer is correct, but could be considered _"unrelated"_ to the real issue of your question, maybe I'll delete it.