# How to save users local time as moment.js object in database?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, datetime, momentjs

I am using api.ai to extract date and time from string. For users input "Today at 9:00" I get abject:

```
{ 
   date: '2017-06-23',
   time: '09:00:00'
}
```

This represents time in users time zone. Now I have to do three things:

1. Display time to user so he can check if I have extracted it correctly. That should be done in his time zone.
2. Save in mongodb db as local time value
3. Save in mongodb db as utc time

To do the first one I use moment.js as follows:

```
moment(date+'T'+time).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, HH:mm");
```

I am not using "Z" and I get "Friday, June 23rd 2017, 09:00" which is exactly what I want.

But I really dont get how to propertly do las two points. As I understand I should save both as datetime objects. I also have user's timezone offset (from facebook profile) so I did this

```
moment(date+'T'+time).subtract(offset, 'hours').toDate()
```

which saved as `ISODate()` but the hours are all wrong.

.toDate() funcion always subtracts three hours which is my servers timezone offset.

I have spent literally 9 hours reading about all the time formats and moment.js. Still I somehow dont get it. This have always been a dark fields for me and I am felling like I am starting to understand but I just need that final push.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44693004/4131048), you can use [`utcOffset`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/) instead of `subtract` or moment-timezone's [`tz()`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/) if you can user timezone, then I think you can use [`utc()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc/), [`local()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/) and/or [`toISOString()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/) to get the last 2 points.

Comment: You are wasting time ( pun not intended ) on this. Times in databases "should" in fact be in UTC. The point is that "local" is relative to and different for every single possible timezone around the globe. The only way you ever reliably walk from one to the other is by starting at a UTC value. If your "string" is local to your present local, the use the `.utc()` method from moment to adjust to UTC and `.toDate()` for the correct type to serialize. Then just store it and walk away. Don't try to adjust things.

Comment: Whole point is When you read from the database the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object returned will always present present a string to the present "locale" and "timezone" purely by the environment, and no extra libraries needed. Internally though the "milliseconds from epoch" is **always** counted from UTC. It's always worked like that, so you are really just overthinking a problem that was solved long before you you even became aware of it.