# Treat UTC date as Local in Javascript/momentjs

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I think this question was asked many times, but I cannot find any answer that suits my needs :(

Lets say I have the following:
`const filter = '2018-08-03T00:00:00.000Z'; //UTC - I get it from client
const timezone = '-0800'; //I get it from account settings in DB`

**The question:**
How I can get from these data, new date that is: `2018-08-03T08:00:00.000Z`?
I tried different ways to convert from utc to local (including momentjs), but what I get is: `2018-08-02T16:00:00.000Z`.

**CODE EXAMPLE**

```
const fromDate = req.payload.date;
console.log(fromDate instanceof Date); //true
console.log(fromDate); //'2018-08-03T00:00:00.000Z'
const newDate = moment(fromDate).tz('America/Yakutat');
console.log(newDate.format()); //actual: '2018-08-02T16:00:00', expected: '2018-08-03T08:00:00'

console.log(newDate.toISOString()); //'2018-08-03T00:00:00.000Z'
```

We are using moment v 2.12, so I cannot use toISOString() with true flag.

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50088484/4131048) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44686385/4131048), you can use [`utcOffset`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/) and/or [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/)

Comment: Are you actually looking to change the time or simply display in the local timezone? Given the zulu in both current and desired examples, I'd be concerned that you are transforming data instead of presentation...

Comment: @VincenzoC I'm actually trying to use moment-timezone, but I do not understand the algorithm of what I need to do. If I use `moment(filter).tz(timezone)`, I'm getting the same result: `2018-08-02T16:00:00.000Z`

Comment: @FissureKing I'm trying to change the date, this date will be used to query the MongoDB, but I need to convert local time to UTC that is saved in mongo, before querying.

Comment: @AlexDn, Are your records all incorrectly stored as well? I'm not intimately familiar with MongoDB's date logic but I would be shocked if it worked this way.

Comment: @AlexDn [`tz`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/) accepts a timezone identifier (like _`America/Los_Angeles`_ or _`Europe/Rome`_), `tz('-0800')` won't work.

Comment: @FissureKing In mongo it is stored as UTC, but I get local time from client. So I need treat local time as UTC. For example timezone "-1", the 18:00 in local, should be 19:00 in UTC, and in Mongo we have UTC saved. So when customer asks items that are > 18:00 at his time, I need to give him items > 19:00 because of timezone.

Comment: @VincenzoC Yep, this is what I used, but result is the same. Maybe I do something wrong.

Comment: @AlexDn how are you _printing_ moment value? Please use [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to display moment value. Moreover consider providing runnable code sample in order to get more accurate answers.

Comment: @VincenzoC I added a code example, would very appreciate to have a help for this! Thanks!

Comment: @AlexDn why you are expecting `2018-08-03T08:00:00`? I think that your code gives the right result, `2018-08-03T00:00:00.000Z` (UTC) is `2018-08-02T16:00:00-08:00` in Yakutat (See [timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=20180803T000000&p1=1440&p2=2382)).

Comment: @VincenzoC Right, if I treat input as UTC, the result is correct, but I want to treat input as local time and then convert it to UTC, so the result would be 2018-08-03T08:00:00 in UTC time. I know it's a bit weird, but this is how our system works.